# Heredoc broken in git bash?

Tags: bash, git-bash, heredoc

I was under the impression that this:

```bash
  cat <<- TEXT
    Hello
    there
  TEXT
```

was supposed to work and would output:

```
Hello
there
```

Instead, it seems to be ignoring the end delimiter.  Even doing this:

```bash
  cat <<- TEXT
    Hello
    there
TEXT
```

Result in:

```
    Hello
    there
```

with the leading whitespace still there.  Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

This question is different from the others because although they do answer the question, they don't answer it directly.  I would be better off going to the man page and reread it until I find the part that I missed.

Comment: With `<<-` only leading tabs are ignored.

Comment: ‍♂️I had assumed horizontal whitespace.  Thx @Cyrus.  I don't use tabs anymore for indenting.  I'll just pipe it through `sed`.

Comment: You already answered the question @Cyrus.  If you want, post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I suggest to close this question with a duplicate.

Comment: They answer, but very indirectly @Cyrus.  I could have gotten that from reading the man page, but I just missed it.  I don't think that this is a duplicate.

Comment: Added "Leading heredocs with spaces" to the duplicate list; I think that one's a bit more narrowly on-point.